# $ in ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

What does the $ symbol mean in ARM template or is there a significance of the symbol? I cant find a reference of it, but I found it on the export template file for the logic Apps:

```
                "parameters": {
                "$connections": {
                    "value": {
                        "azureblob": {
                            "connectionId": "[parameters('value1')]",
                            "connectionName": "connectionName",
                            "id": "/subscriptions/xxxxx-xxx-xxx-xxxx-e96113994f0a/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/westeurope/managedApis/azureblob"
                        },
                        "sql": {
                            "connectionId": "[parameters('connections_sql_externalid')]",
                            "connectionName": "sql",
                            "id": "/subscriptions/xxxxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxx-e96113994f0a/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/westeurope/managedApis/sql"
                        },
                        "sftp": {
                            "connectionId": "[parameters('connections_sftpName_externalid')]",
                            "connectionName": "sftpName",
                            "id": "/subscriptions/xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-e96113994f0a/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/westeurope/managedApis/sftpwithssh"
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$` is used to declare a parameter in a specific case.

For example, the `$connections` parameter here in your case is for the connection values to use at logic app runtime. In the ARM template of your logic app, logic app's resource definition also works with connection resource definitions in these ways:

- Inside your workflow definition, the `parameters` object declares a
  `$connections` parameter for the connection values to use at logic app
  runtime. Also, the trigger or action that creates a connection uses
  the corresponding values that pass through this $connections
  parameter.
- Outside your workflow definition but still inside your logic app's
  resource definition, another `parameters` object sets the values to use
  at runtime for the `$connections` parameter by referencing the
  corresponding template parameters. These values use template
  expressions to reference resources that securely store the metadata
  for the connections in your logic app.

For more details, you can refer to this article [Connection resource definitions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-azure-resource-manager-templates-overview#connection-resource-definitions).